# Why are there so few magical protective items in the Wizarding World?

Tags: harry-potter

There were a bunch of times when some less experienced wizards (read teenagers) were able to temporarily beat much more experienced wizards by an element of surprise. On top of that, wizards were pretty much powerless, if a wand was knocked out of their hands.

This raises a question: Why don't wizards (especially those who have to participate in some battles) wear some magical protective items (to protect from simpler attacks, to get back their wands and so on)?

Comment: You mean like the shield spell? Or the listening ears like the kind the Weasley twins made? Or protecting places with portkeys?

Comment: I guess during peacetimes (which was most of Harry's time from the average Wizards point of view, really) nobody really bothered?

Comment: How about putting a string on the wand so you can't drop it?

Comment: @ClintEastwood All the wizarding world think think they're too smart for such simple solutions. Gotta make a long-winded retrieval spell instead!

Comment: @LincolnMan And the Fidelius charm. Yada yada yada. Lots of protective spells, apart from the "old magic" of "loving sacrifice".

Answer (score 26):

They did. Half Blood Prince, Chapter Six:

> “We’ve just developed this more serious line,” said Fred. “Funny how it happened …”
>   “You wouldn’t believe how many people, even people who work at the Ministry, can’t do a decent Shield Charm,” said George. “ ’Course, they didn’t have you teaching them, Harry.”
>   “That’s right. … Well, we thought Shield Hats were a bit of a laugh, you know, challenge your mate to jinx you while wearing it and watch his face when the jinx just bounces off. But the Ministry bought five hundred for all its support staff! And we’re still getting massive orders!”
>   “So we’ve expanded into a range of Shield Cloaks, Shield Gloves …”
>   “… I mean, they wouldn’t help much against the Unforgivable Curses, but for minor to moderate hexes or jinxes …”

It's entirely possible people do use them, and we just don't notice. Harry, as a narrator, doesn't tend to pay attention to this sort of thing.

Comment: Stop dumping on Harry's narration skills, he's got other things on his mind

Comment: Hang on, Harry's supposed to be the narrator?!

Comment: Although it begs the question why the MoM hadn't thought of it before Fred and George did.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees exactly. It seems before the twins there was not much of it (if we discount Dung's fake 'protection against dark magic' potions).

Comment: @Muzer it's third-person limited, Harry isn't telling the story but the entity that is can generally only see the world through Harry's eyes. Either that or Harry took to referring to himself in the third person when he started writing his memoirs (now that's a story I'd like to hear).

Comment: This shows that they didn't until a couple of high-schoolers invented it, and towards the end of the series.  So for the hundreds (thousands?) of years prior, wizards never used this stuff.  If it were actually a things that wizards did, then the ministry would have already been using this stuff before the Weasley twins came around.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I recall times when we saw things that aren't through Harry's eyes. Admittedly not too many of them, but there were a few. I guess on the whole you're right though.

Comment: @industry7 Why do you assume that? There's no reason to think that this was the first time something like this had come up. Maybe Fred and George were the first to market it in this era, or in Britain specifically, but we have no evidence that similar equipment isn't used elsewhere, or hadn't been used previously.

Comment: It's possible that it's not described. However, it doesn't explain why simple Expelliarmus knocks a wand from experienced wizards _in the middle of the battle_. It wouldn't happen if there were having a lot of protective charms.

Comment: Another possibility is: it wasn't done on a large scale beforehand. Some resourceful wizards might have made protection charms/enchantments/thingamabobs before, but they never thought to reveal how to make them or distributed them (after all, they could be used against them). Or the creation costs were too high (think of Harry's protective charm, he got it because his mother died for him)... [Also, most renowned wizards tried not to fight at the front lines and sent cannon fodder first, e.g. death eaters]

Answer (score 7):

In The Half-Blood Prince, the good guys use the most powerful protection, the only *other one* that works against Avada Kedavra : Felix Felicis.

> “Neville and Professor Flitwick are both hurt, but Madam Pomfrey says they’ll be all right. And a Death Eater’s dead, he got hit by a Killing Curse that huge blond one was firing off everywhere — Harry, if we hadn’t had your Felix potion, I think we’d all have been killed, but everything seemed to just miss us —”

Chapter 29 of The Half-Blood Prince.

You can't resist Avada Kedavra (if your name is not Potter) if you are hit, no matter what magical protection you have. But in order to survive all you have to do is not getting hit.

Comment: Your reasoning. If I can't protect from the worst spell then it doesn't make a sense to protect. However, it's not completely true. You can avoid being hit by Avada Kadavra (just jump from it). However, if you lose your wand, you are pretty much done. And it looks like Expelliarmus is much faster spell than Avada Kadavra. As result, it makes a lot of sense to protect from spells like that.

Answer (score 0):

Usually adult wizards, who participate in battles, do use very strong protecting spells can only make well cast spells a little weaker or no weaker at all, like Avada Kedavra. I think that's why, they don't use protective clothes.
  It might be also cheating in battles. Wizards usually do use some kind of rules in their battles.

Comment: Can you provide a source for the fact that they wouldn't help block spells and that there are "rules" to battles?

Comment: In Harry Potter 5, when Harry where in ministry of magic, he used varjelum against death eaters. I don't remember the spell they used, and I have readed the book only in Finnish.

Comment: yeah because following the rules is more important than surviving. Especially when you are a bad guy.

Comment: ("Varjelum tyystilys" is [Protego Totalum](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Protego_totalum))

Comment: Well right. That's nice point dna, and thanks Aneves.

Comment: I answered @dna. Even if you can't protect from the worst spell, you still will be better off if you protect from weaker spells.